# order values by median instead of mean

Tags: r

I am want to change the function below so that `value` is reordered based on median value and not mean value. Changing `mean` with `median` did not work

```
sign.m$miRNA <- with(sign.m, reorder(miRNA,as.numeric(as.character(value)),mean))

> head(sign.m)
             miRNA variable  value
1   hsa-miR-99a-5p      100  -1.37
2 hsa-miR-92a-1-5p      100   3.11
3     hsa-miR-9-5p      100  -3.60
4   hsa-miR-877-5p      100   2.08
5     hsa-miR-7-5p      100   3.37
6  hsa-miR-642a-5p      100  -5.10
```

Comment: Selecting more appropriate tags might attract people that can answer your question, this has nothing to do with `ggplot2` as far as i can see. Try `r`and perhaps `reorder`.

Comment: `reorder` will change the order of `miRNA` _levels_ based on the mean/median value of `value`, not the order of rows in the data.frame. This works for me `xy <- data.frame(grp = sample(letters[1:3], size = 10, replace = TRUE), a = runif(10)); with(xy, reorder(x = grp, X = a, FUN = median))`.

Comment: It would be better if you provide a reproducible sample (variable values). Basically what you have and what you want to get.